# Autocorrelation of an AR(1) process

Tags: r, time-series, autocorrelation, autoregressive, acf-pacf

I am learning about this AR process.
According to the book I'm reading, the autocorrelatio function of a stationary process:
$$y_t = c + \phi y_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t, \quad \quad |\phi|< 1$$

is as follows: $\rho(h)= \frac{\gamma(h)}{\gamma(0)} = \phi^h$

Which means a slow exponential decay for successive lags, hence revealing that the series does behaves as an AR(1) process. So, I can not understand why in this case the autocorrelation function drops but then grows again.

`` set.seed(123456) 
y <- arima.sim(n = 100, list(ar = 0.9), innov=rnorm(100)) `
op <- par(no.readonly=TRUE) 
layout(matrix(c(1, 1, 2, 3), 2, 2, byrow=TRUE)) plot.ts(y, ylab='') 
acf(y, main='Autocorrelations', ylab='', ylim=c(-1, 1), ci.col = "black") 
pacf(y, main='Partial Autocorrelations', ylab='', ylim=c(-1, 1), ci.col = "black") 
par(op) ``

[image]

Any explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's perfectly normal when you have only `100` samples. Take it `n=1000` and you'll see an exponentially dropping autocorrelation curve. Small samples have less tendency to obey theoretical results.